# Prove using induction the 2 color theorem proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A box with 4 closed sides has $n$ straight lines going all the way across it.Lines can be drawn vertically, horizontally, and diagonally at any angle as long as it is straight and spans the entire box.

The base case is of course only 1 line which separates the box into 2 colors, black and white.

How can I show using induction that for any $n$ lines, the box can still be colored with only black and white.

I am familiar with regular induction however this concept feels too abstract for me to grasp

Comment: Try drawing an example. Start with, say, five lines, and 2-color the result, then add a sixth line and see how you can change your coloring to 2-color the result in the simplest way.

Comment: however even if I am able to show that 5 or 6 lines is able to be 2-colored, it does not prove that any $n$ lines is able to be 2-colored

Comment: is it even possible to show with regular induction?

Comment: Yes, but thinking about a concrete example gives you insight into the general problem.

Comment: @NoahDeng It is quite possible to show it with induction. But before you can write a formal proof, you have to first understand why the statement is true; and that will come from working with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you already have $n$ lines drawn and they colour the box Black and White.

Add 1 new line anywhere. For every region below the new line, invert that region's colour. For every region above, leave the colour the same.

Hence if $n$ lines can colour, then so can $n+1$ (inductive proof).

Comment: does there exist another 'simplier' way to prove this other than induction?

Comment: Define 'simpler'. This way seems pretty simple.

Comment: induction is widely considered an extremely simple proof method